# Run time error 9 - subscription out of range

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting constant error of "out of range" but the reference of the range is correct, please help me to solve the error:  the error or bug in the coding is highlighted as bold in the below mentioned code:

```
Sub CopyStuff()

    **Sheets("Data-BNF").Range("D11:X76").Copy**
    Sheets("Storage-OI").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Comment: Try specifying the workbook in the reference. It's now trying to copy from sheet `Data-BNF`in the active WB

Answer (score 0):

Modify the below and try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Copy()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim Lastrow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set ws1 = .Worksheets("Data-BNF")
        Set ws2 = .Worksheets("Storage-OI")
    End With

    Lastrow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    ws1.Range("D11:X76").Copy
    'Try the **ONE of the below**
    ws2.Range("C" & Lastrow + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValue
    ws2.Range("C" & Lastrow + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```